# How do I know whether my code has compiled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am learning to code in C++ mostly through self-study. I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio IDE. I'm used to very simple IDEs (think MATLAB) where you basically press "run," whereas visual studio gives me options to clean, build, etcetera.

Anyway, my question is how do I know whether my code has compiled successfully? I suspect this is such a basic thing that it's rarely written down.

Comment: Expanded into the the land of testing: Introduce things that you _know_ are incorrect. If everything works as before, you know that your new code wasn't exercised. Not a bad question in my book.

Comment: You'll get error messages if the code didn't compile. I have no clue what you're asking here??

Comment: There's no simple "run" button in visual studio. There are things like clean, build, rebuild, a debug mode ... at what point is code compiled and are any error messages for compile time errors?

Comment: I have read at a conceptual level about compile time errors and run time errors but I don't know how they are distinguished in an IDE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are tons of situations where you change code and feel uncertain if the build system _actually_ used it. I've heard the request for a "clean build" more than a thousand times when people didn't trust my build system :-)

Comment: Of course there's a run button, it just does every of the needed steps.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is it the one that says "local windows debugger" ? If I get an error indicated by a red circle with a cross in it, does that mean my code didn't compile?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand that the question is basic, but I have only spoken of whether my code "ran" or "worked" before. My understanding is that "compiled" is not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Any help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-2-build?view=msvc-160 ?

Comment: @user37344 Well, it's not like there doesn't exist a documentation for the visual studio IDE, and explanations of the different panes you see arranged around the editing window. One of them (at the bottom) shows the compiler error messages, and what happens when the program starts up in debugging mode. There are also tons of tutorials how to use the IDE available on the internet. Sorry, we're not a tutoring site here.

Comment: This may be a hard thing to say, but: you need to make the best possible effort you can to figure this out ***by yourself***. There are very few problems in C++ that have a cookie-cutter, paint-by-numbers solution, and no two C++ compilation errors are alike. You will learn, very quickly, that the most valuable skill a C++ developer can learn is how to figure things out. And, in the grand scheme of things, figuring out how a compiler works ranks pretty much among the most basic things to figure out. If this is a challenge, how do you think you'll do deciphering a typical 20-line error message?

Comment: You will likely find switching the tab in the bottom pane from the default of Error List to Output. Output contains the full build output of the last run (in plain text which is really useful when asking questions about error messages on Stack Overflow) and doesn't contain any of the noise from Intellisense. Often the more detailed information in Output  contains exactly what you needed to understand the problem. I don't do much with Visual Studio, but I haven't used the Error List tab in years.

Comment: I also recommend looking at the Output tab.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I have done a bit of debugging using both the error list and output windows, so I'm familiar with those. I was under the impression that compilation errors were separated out from others ... maybe not.

Comment: ***how do I know whether my code has compiled successfully?*** It says that at the end of the output tab listing. Here is what I have for one of my work projects: ***========== Build: 22 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 4 skipped ==========***

Comment: @drescherjm It says Build: x successful, y failed. Is that the same thing then?

Comment: Yes that is the first thing I look at as a professional developer.

Comment: @drescherjm Fantastic, that's what I didn't know. If you make that an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226500/discussion-between-user37344-and-drescherjm).

Comment: if y is greater than zero, something went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio you get a message at the end of the output in the Output Tab like this:

```
========== Build: 22 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 4 skipped ==========
```

This message is displayed after every build of your solution. I usually check this at the end of each build to verify that the build has worked. If any projects are listed as failed I read the entire output from the top looking for the first error in the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run you can press **Ctrl+F5** if you are in windows. I don't know the shortcut under MacOS but I think it will be **Cmd+F5**. If you want to debug your code using Microsoft Visual Studio tools, you just have to press **F5** under windows and again, I'm not sure what it is under MacOS but I think it's just **F5**.

[image: Using debug tools]
If you click on the **green arrow turned 90°**, it will be debugged using the MVS debugging tool.

[image]
You can also do it by pressing the debug button in the upper section and pressing **Start Debugging** or **Start without Debugging** to start it without debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the chat, I found that I was just confused about some terminology and I accepted an answer that cleared it up for me.